# How to zip and unzip files that do not fit in memory with Python

Tags: zip, compression

I have a lot of files which sum up to more than 125GB. I want to compress them because they will be transferred over the internet quite often, so I think about zipping them before transfer and then decompressing, but a colleague told me that wit would have to fit in memory in order to do it using Python.

Is there a way to do it without using up all my memory? It is possible that the built-in ZipFile module already avoids loading all data into memory (and that my colleague is mistaken), but I have not found any source with the answer.

Answer (score 3):

> so I think about zipping them before transfer and then decompressing, but a colleague told me that wit would have to fit in memory in order to do it using Python.

This is not true, and certainly not true if you control both ends (the zip format does technically allow for zip files that can't be stream-unzipped, but I'm yet to actually see one)

You can use [stream-zip](https://github.com/uktrade/stream-zip) and [stream-unzip](https://github.com/uktrade/stream-unzip) to do this (full disclosure: written mostly by me). Both avoid not only storing any zip file or member file in memory, but also avoids even having to have them on disk - random access is not required.

The details depend a bit on where the files are and how you want to transfer them, but an example to stream zip:

```py
from datetime import datetime
from stream_zip import ZIP_64, stream_zip

def unzipped_files():
    modified_at = datetime.now()
    perms = 0o600

    def file_data():
        # An iterable that yields bytes of the file
        # e.g. could come from disk or an http request
        yield b'Some bytes 1'
        yield b'Some bytes 2'

    # ZIP_64 mode
    yield 'my-file-1.txt', modified_at, perms, ZIP_64, file_data()

# An iterable of bytes to then, for example, save to disk,
# or send via an http request
zipped_chunks = stream_zip(unzipped_files())
```

and an example to stream unzip:

```py
from stream_unzip import stream_unzip

for file_name, file_size, unzipped_chunks in stream_unzip(zipped_chunks):
    # Can save the unzipped chunks to disk here instead of printing
    # them out
    for chunk in unzipped_chunks:
        print(chunk)
```

---

In the above examples `zipped_chunks` and `unzipped_chunks` are iterables that yield `bytes`. And to save any such iterables to disk, you can use a pattern like this:

```py
with open('my.zip', 'wb') as f:
    for chunk in zipped_chunks:
        f.write(chunk)
```

Comment: How do we store this iterable of bytes(zipped_chunks) into a disk?

Comment: @PROTOCOL I've added some details to the end of the answer to show how to save it to disk

Answer (score 1):

You could use [gzip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gzip.html) instead, which more readily supports stream compression and decompression.